# can't create PDF on Sublime text 3 Windows

Tags: pdf, latexmk, sublime-text

my system check told me latexmk is available, but every time I press "Ctrl+B" it told me : 

`error: The command line tool "latexmk" is not available on your path. Please check your settings.`

Please help me with it!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved, but never closed (no accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it's a stupid mistake that I also installed Latexing and it was the default one. So although my Latextools set correct, it didn't work... uninstall Latexing will fix this.

Comment: how to make work with latexing then?